# JQuery FullCalendar: Animate View Change/Toggle

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) in my application. I have removed the default buttons for changing views provided by the plug-in and placed my own instead on click of which I am using the `changeView` property to toggle between `agendaWeek` and `agendaDay` views.

But the change is quite abrupt. So I was wondering if any of could help me apply some transition animation using JQuery.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your next, previous and today click functions, you can apply jquery slideToggle to animate the calender:

```
        nextButtonClick: function () {
            viewModel.animateCalendar();
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('next');
        },
        previousButtonClick: function () {
            viewModel.animateCalendar();
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('prev');                
        },
        todayButtonClick: function () {
            viewModel.animateCalendar();
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('today');                
        },
        animateCalendar: function () {
            // try and animate transition
            $('#calendar').slideToggle();
            $('#calendar').slideToggle();
        },
```

By default this will slide it up and then back down again but you can add parameters to change the direction, speed etc. http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fadeOut` and in the complete function show again the calendar and change the view.

Code:

```
$('#mycalendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title'
    },
    editable: true,
    events: [{
        title: 'event1',
        start: '2014-05-02'
    }, {
        title: 'event2',
        start: '2014-05-10'
    }]
});

$("#change").click(function () {
    $('#mycalendar').fadeOut("slow", function () {
        $('#mycalendar').show();
        $('#mycalendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'basicWeek')
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/A7Vc6/